# Which fonts to use with pinyin?

Tags: fonts, xetex, cjk

I have a document which contains some pinyin. I find that many fonts I tried, however, don't contain all of the tone marks.

I have set up the following test file which shows all of the possible letters used within pinyin which contain tone marks:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\setCJKmainfont{Adobe Song Std}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item ā ē ī ō ū ǖ Ā Ē Ī Ō Ū Ǖ
        \item á é í ó ú ǘ Á É Í Ó Ú Ǘ
        \item ǎ ě ǐ ǒ ǔ ǚ Ǎ Ě Ǐ Ǒ Ǔ Ǚ
        \item à è ì ò ù ǜ À È Ì Ò Ù Ǜ
        \item a e i o u ü A E I O U Ü
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

When I build the file, quite a number of letters are missing. When I view the file, I see many boxes. Yet `xelatex` does not tell me any errors.

- What font settings should I consider which will look great and have all of the letters I need?
- As `xelatex` did not display any errors, does that mean the PDF is fine, but my PDF reader has a problem?

Comment: Missing chars is not an error per se, but *TeX reports them in the log, check it.

Comment: I compile your code and get almost right document, I just use `Adobe Song Std` since I have no `Minion Pro` font. I only miss ǖ and Ǖ, it's odd.

Comment: Some serifed fonts that have the full range of accent: Charis SIL, Gentium Plus, Linux Libertine O, CMU Serif, DejaVu Serif, Times New Roman.

Comment: @AlanMunn,follow your comment, I get the full range of accent, thanks.

Comment: @AlanMunn Would you turn your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends on the font whether it has a full range of accents.  The following are some serifed fonts that have the full range of accents.  Other than Times New Roman, all are free, OpenType fonts.

- Charis SIL
- Gentium Plus
- Linux Libertine O
- CMU Serif
- DejaVu Serif
- Times New Roman.

Comment: `DejaVu Sans` also seems to have them.

Answer (score 2):

The Brill

http://www.brill.com/author-gateway/brill-fonts

Free for non-commercial use.